# Changing weights of graph in discover_vertex visitor

Tags: boost, boost-graph, visitor-pattern

Is it possible to change the weights of a graph while an algorithm (dijkstra in this case) is running?

In the following code I get a compiler error:

> 'g' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const

```
struct WeightVisitor : public boost::default_dijkstra_visitor
{
    template <typename Vertex, typename Graph> void
        discover_vertex(Vertex v, Graph & g)
    {
        /// Get parent
        Vertex parentVertex = boost::in_edges(v, g).first->m_source;

        typedef typename boost::graph_traits< Graph >::edge_descriptor edge_t;
        edge_t edgeDescriptor;

        std::pair<edge_t, bool> ed = boost::edge(parentVertex, v, g);
        if (tTrue == ed.second)
        {
            edgeDescriptor = ed.first;

            //put(&EdgeValueType::weight, tree, edgeDescriptor, i_wtNewWeight);
            g[edgeDescriptor].weight = rand() % 100;
            std::cout << "TimeStamp: " << g[edgeDescriptor].weight << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Warning: No edge between input vertices" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Without the reference I am working on a copy of the graph which is not what I want. Instead I would like to change the weights on the graph directly.

Here is the call to Dijkstra shortes path algorithm:

```
boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, root,
        boost::weight_map(boost::get(&tEdge::weight, g))
        .distance_map(boost::make_iterator_property_map(distances.begin(), boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g)))
        .predecessor_map(boost::make_iterator_property_map(predecessors.begin(), boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g)))
        .visitor(sWeightVisitor)
    );
```

For vertices and edges I use bundled properties:

```
struct tVertex
{
    int id;
};

struct tEdge
{
    double weight;
};
```

And the definition of the graph

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
        boost::mapS,
        boost::vecS,
        boost::bidirectionalS,
        tVertex, tEdge>
        graph_t;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the weight is dangerous, depending on the algorithm. You could violate some invariants of the algorithm, making the behaviour undefined (like, maybe it will never terminate).

But if you know what you're doing, just keep a pointer-to-mutable-graph in the visitor:

```
struct WeightVisitor : public boost::default_dijkstra_visitor
{
    graph_t* _graph;

...
```

And instantiate it with the address:

```
WeightVisitor sWeightVisitor { &g };
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it this way. Do you know if all the visitor event points expect a const reference or a copy of the graph? Or are there some event visitors that allow the graph to be changed? I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation.

Comment: I think they all take a const reference. In fact, check the algorithm function. I think it would already receive the graph argument by const reference (because why not, you want to be able to run the algorithm without having to make a muscle copy of it first). If so, then you know, and also why.

Comment: You are right, [boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html) expects the graph to be a const reference. I think in the documentation they forgot the `const` in the named parameter version of Dijkstra. However the `const` is also present in the [header file](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp)